# While installing package from PIP it using private repo/server

Tags: python, pip, package, devpi

While I'm installing packages with pip it installing it from my private instead of public/official repo... How to fix it?

Edit:

```
(test)  mymac@pc137  ~/workspace  pip install pacman
```

`Collecting pacman`

```
User for devpi.packageserver.com:
```

It seems that devpi has been used by pip... How to switch off devpi? I don't want to use it while installing packages with pip...

Comment: more details about what command you used etc will help..

Comment: what he said ^, there are no details here

Comment: Eddited. Is it related with devpi?

Comment: Check whether you have a file `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf` or a `pip.conf` in your virtualenv's dir, comment out or remove lines setting `index-url` or `extra-index-url`.

Comment: @hoefling DUDE! That's it! Thanks! Where I can add +1 for you?!  my pip.conf was in `Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/pip`

Comment: Glad I could help! I have added an answer which you can upvote/accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional server usage can be persisted in the configuration file `pip.conf` (or `pip.ini` on Windows). Since you stated you're on MacOS, it seems you have found the correct location (according to the [official docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration)):

> The names and locations of the configuration files vary slightly across platforms. You may have per-user, per-virtualenv or site-wide (shared amongst all users) configuration:
>
> **Per-user:**
>
> ...
>
> On macOS the configuration file is `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf` if directory `$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip` exists else `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf`.
>
> There are also a legacy per-user configuration file which is also respected, these are located at:
>
> On Unix and macOS the configuration file is: `$HOME/.pip/pip.conf`

Find the config file, open it with an editor and comment out (or remove) lines setting the `index-url`/`extra-index-url` options.